# Gradle error when trying to create a new project in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting Gradle error every time when I am creating a new project in AndroidStudio? I have installed and reinstalled android studio on mac but the error still appearing and getting the same error.
 Below my errors from Logcat.

> /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/d531dbb8e7f408824a92fa6cc86908a2/res/layout/select_dialog_item_material.xml
>
> Error:(31, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingStart' with value '?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart').
>   Error:(32, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingEnd' with value '?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd').
>   /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Desktop/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/select_dialog_item_material.xml
>
> Error:(31, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingStart' with value '?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart').
>   Error:(32, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingEnd' with value '?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd').
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   process
>   /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt
>   with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar
>   -M /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Desktop/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Desktop/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
>   -m -J /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Desktop/MyApplication2/app/build/generated/source/r/debug
>   -F /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Desktop/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_
>   --custom-package com.example.yodgorbekkomilov.myapplication -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Desktop/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>   --no-version-vectors}
>
> Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Users/yodgorbekkomilov/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1 Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > Failed to execute aapt

```
below my buld.gradle file

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yodgorbekkomilov.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:(31, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingStart' with value '?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart'). Error:(32, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingEnd' with value '?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd').

It seems `?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd` has been removed from the API 26. Try using some other value for the `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` attributes inside `select_dialog_item_material.xml` file of yours.